# Dbpedia alternative names

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have been trying to get the names of singers along with their alternative names from dbpedia. Any idea what I am doing wrong? When I include alias I get no results

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?singer ?alternativeName
WHERE { 
 ?x dbo:musicalArtist ?singer.
 ?x dbp:alias ?alternativeName.
}
```

Comment: Hi @StanislavKralin, I like your answer more than mine. Post it as answer and I will vote it up.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse, just edit you answer, I'll delete my comments :).

Comment: Hah! :D Nah! I won't do that. I will not be happy posting an answer that was not my insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no aliases. To verify run with OPTIONAL, i.e.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?singer ?alternativeName
WHERE { 
   ?x dbo:musicalArtist ?singer.
   OPTIONAL{?x dbp:alias ?alternativeName.}
}
```

Update: Stanislav Kralin's comment is most likely [exactly](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%3Fsinger%20%3Fname%20%3FalternativeName%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%3Fsinger%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3AMusicalArtist.%0D%0A%20%3Fsinger%20dbo%3Aalias%20%3FalternativeName.%0D%0A%20%3Fsinger%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname.%0D%0A%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fname)%20%3D%20%27en%27%20%26%26%20lang(%3FalternativeName)%20%3D%20%27en%27)%20%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml) what you need.

Comment: I suppose the OP need something like [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fsinger+%3Fname+%3FalternativeName%0D%0AWHERE+{+%0D%0A+%3Fsinger+rdf%3Atype+dbo%3AMusicalArtist.%0D%0A+%3Fsinger+dbo%3Aalias+%3FalternativeName.%0D%0A+%3Fsinger+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fname.%0D%0A+FILTER+(lang(%3Fname)+%3D+%27en%27+%26%26+lang(%3FalternativeName)+%3D+%27en%27)+%0D%0A}+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml): `dbo:alias` instead of `dbp:alias`, `dbo:musicalArtist` should be a class, etc. BTW, Jon Bon Jovi is missing in this list.

Comment: what if they don't have an alias? Can they still be shown with no alias field?

Comment: Yes, just add OPTIONAL and it will still show with no alternative.